# How to Open a Links in a div tag in same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="WebForm1.aspx">Form1</a>  
<a href="WebForm2.aspx">Form2</a>  
<a href="WebForm3.aspx">Form3</a>   
<div id="content"> </div>  ``
```

Here I have three links in my page. If i click the link it will go to the assigned page .Now I want to load this link into my div tag. There are some answers already available but not working.

I have tried doing this (a clarification from comments):

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('a').on("click", function () {           
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $("#content").load(this.getAttribute('href')); 
});
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Maybe someone can explain why your attempt isn't working...

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').on("click", function () {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content").load(this.getAttribute('href'));
        });

Comment: Are you including the jQuery link to your web page and have you checked for errors in your browser console?

Comment: Am not included anything

Comment: Well the attempt you have posted is `jQuery` and to use that you must link or download a copy of their library. Also `e` is causing the problem as you never pass anything so that would need to be `event` I suggest you open your browser console while working with javascript. You will see errors logged in there (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `jQuery` you must link to the [**jQuery library**](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js) or **[Download a copy](https://jquery.com/download/)** 
and link to it.

> **Example:** Link to the [**jQuery library**](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Once you have done that you can then start using `jQuery`.

`jQuery` has  a [DOM ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, it's recommended you place all of your jQuery within this to prevent any error upon page load. This will ensure the jQuery is only run when the page had loaded the content "Page/DOM is ready".

> **Example:** [**DOM ready**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
//Script/Function go here...
});
```

Putting these together your attempt should work after replacing `e` with `event` or if you pass event into the function.

> **Example:** Passing the `event` as `e`

```
$('a').on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#content").load(this.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

> **Example:** Without passing the `event`

```
$('a').on("click", function(){
event.preventDefault();
$("#content").load(this.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

Your overall script should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('a').on("click", function(){
event.preventDefault();
$("#content").load(this.getAttribute('href'));
});
});
```

> **Working Demo >** [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2nkek4hb/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('a').on("click", function(){
event.preventDefault();
//This will run just fine for files stored within  your own domain
//$("#content").load(this.getAttribute('href'));

// Load External pages.
$("#content").html('<object data="'+this.getAttribute('href')+'" />');
});
});
```

```css
#content{height:250;width:500px;}
#content object{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">jQuery 3.1.1</a>  
<a href="https://api.jquery.com/ready/">jQuery Dom Read</a>  
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/2nkek4hb/1/">Form3</a>   
<div id="content"></div>
```

I prefer to keep my javascript/jQuery between the `<head>` tags butit's entirely up to you.

---

> Snipped Update:

If you apply CSS `height:100%;` and `width:100%;` to the object then it should fit the size of `#content` I have edited the snippet but the changes are shown below.

**CSS:**

```
#content{height:250;width:500px;}
#content object{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

---

If you have any question about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: It simply good.But this will load in a div tag which is very minimum in size.How to affect that?I applied style in  content div tag but its not working

Comment: @monica I have updated the answer, i hope this will fix your problem. If not please explain in more detail as to the problem you're having and I will try fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Just a working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.link').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#content").html('<object data="' + href + '" />');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com">Link - Site 1</a>
<a class="link" href="http://tired.com">Link - Site 2</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: It simply good.But this will load in a div tag which is very minimum in size.How to affect that?

Comment: How to affect the size of that div ?@DBS

Comment: Use CSS to change the size of that DIV.

Comment: I did it .But no results.

Comment: Hmm, try: <div id="content" style="width: 600px;height: 250px;"></div>

Comment: No ...Its not affect the content div.

Comment: I've added a border to see your result, try now: <div id="content" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;border: 1px solid #000;overflow: hidden;"></div>

Comment: Its affect the div but the link loaded in a small view .Check with https://jsfiddle.net/2nkek4hb/1/